# Is it okay to give bone from one pitbull to another pitbull while they are separated, although they have fought before?

Tags: dogs

One pitbull fought with the other, and in the process one pitbulls chew bone (a big cow bone) was left behind and the other pitbull has been chewing on it. Is it okay to retrieve that bone and give it to the dog who's bone it originally was?

Both dogs are separated, but I'm just wondering because the scent of the dog who currently has the chew toy is on the toy, and so I don't know if that may cause any problems.

Just looking for some advice, maybe from someone who is experienced with pits. I am a first time pit owner (he is a rescue) and have had my pit for 4 months, so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Bones in general are not good for dogs, they damage their teeth (wear to the pulp over time, slab fractures etc.) they can also splinter/break and get stuck in the esophagus/GI tract. Take the bones away.

Be sure that there are no toys lying around when multiple dogs are together to prevent fights in the future.

Assuming both dogs in question are healthy then yes you may return the toy to the original dog with no problem.

Glad to hear you adopted, good luck! :)